# Int32 can't be converted to gcl_queue_flags

Tags: macos, swift, opencl

My attempt to use OpenCL with the Swift language (using xcode6 Dp4, Yosemite DP4) fails:

```
import Cocoa 
import OpenCL 
- 
- 
var queue: dispatch_queue_t = gcl_create_dispatch_queue(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, nil)
-
-
```

An error message comes up at "var queue ..."-line; "Int32 can't be converted to gcl_queue_flags". The line of code works perfectly when using Objective-C or C. Testing OpenCL (and GCDas well) seems not work in playground.

Answer (score 3):

This is an issue with the way the `CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU` macro is imported to Swift — it's an Int32, but the function takes UInt64. So you can use `cl_queue_flags(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU)` to convert it. You might also want to [file a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com).